# Загрузка файла на сервер PHP

Tags: php, upload

Пытаюсь загрузить файл на сервер, код формы:

```
    <input name='file' type='file'/>
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Загрузить\"><br><br /><br />
```

Код обработчик:

```
if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
print_r($_FILES)."<br>";
  if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1024*1*1024)
   {
     echo ("Размер файла превышает 1 мегабайт");
     exit;
   }
   if(copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/images/logo/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
   {
     echo("Файл успешно загружен" 
    );
     echo("Характеристики файла:"
     );
     echo("Имя файла: ");
     echo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     echo("Размер файла: ");
     echo($_FILES["file"]["size"]);
     echo("Каталог для загрузки: ");
     echo($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
     echo("Тип файла: ");
     echo($_FILES["file"]["type"]);
   } else {
      echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
   }

}
```

Что получаю:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => webmoney2.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /var/www/arashvg/data/mod-tmp/phpFJdUdN
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 768
        )

)
Ошибка загрузки файла.
```

Пробовал адрес папки куда загружать менять на "images/logo/", "../images/logo/", "./images/logo/", безрезультатно... права на папку стоят 777.

Подсжите где ошибка, никак не могу понять (((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А права на запись в директории есть?
Перед

```
  if(copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/images/logo/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
```

Пишем

```
if (!is_writable("/images/logo")) {
    die("Запись в каталог запрещена");
}
```

Это раз. 
В корне у Вас врятли есть /images. Это два.
Полный путь укажите /var/www/site.ru/images/logo

Comment: @dimka3210, лучше использовать move_uploaded_file() вместо copy()

Comment: папка /images/logo какраз корне

код if (!is_writable("/images/logo")) выдает ошибку о запрете записи

права на папку images и все файли иподкаталоги 0777.

путь всюду прописал var/www/monitor-obmen.ru/images/logo/

Comment: @arashvg, в корне диска? Или в корне проекта?

Comment: @dimka3210, в корне проекта

Comment: @arashvg, пробуйте так:

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/logo/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        // файл загружен
    }

Comment: @Deonis, Спасибо! Работает!